# Where do I set the configuration mapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am reading in a book (Professional Hadoop Solutions) that JVM reuse can be enabled by specifying the job configuration `mapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks`.  My question is do we need to set this in the Driver class?

I tried looking for this configuration in `mapreduce.Job` object, and I don't find it.  Could this API be replaced elsewhere in the version of Hadoop I am using?  Or am I not looking in the right place?  I am using Hadoop version 1.0.3.

I also tried to look for the older property `mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks`, and I couldn't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define it in mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks</name>
    <value>-1</value>
</property>
```

Use it when you have shorter task that run for a definite period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Your source is referring to the newer Hadoop configuration API for Hadoop 2.x (YARN). Within the shift to YARN a lot of configuration names have been revised. The changes are documented [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html) on the [the offical site](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/index.html) for the related Hadoop release (in this case the by Amazon's Elastic MapReduce adopted version 2.4.0).

It explicitly mentions the old configuration name `mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks` has been replaced by the new name `mapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks`.

Furthermore the documentation for the MapReduce [default configuration](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml) says this for `mapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks`:

> How many tasks to run per jvm. If set to -1, there is no limit.

The default configuration for Hadoop 1.2.1 (compatible configuration API to 1.0.3) can be found on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.collector/1.2.1/mapred-default.xml) for example.

Regarding your question, where to set this property. It either can be set

- for the whole cluster in `${HADOOP_CONF_DIR}/mapred-site.xml`,
- or you specify it in the configuration of your Job (or JobContext), as long it is not declared **final** within your cluster:
  `job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks","-1");`